# How to hide page number on full-page float?

Tags: floats, page-numbering

I've created a TikZ figure and compiled it to pdf. In my main TeX document, I include it using:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
% ...
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{tikzfigure.pdf}
    \caption{My caption.}
    \label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}
```

The figure is large enough to cover an entire page. How can I hide the page number on the page that the float ends up on?

Is there a better solution for including full-page TikZ figures?

Comment: Apologies if my question is poor, I didn't realise that. Should I include a screenshot or a MWE?

Comment: You should always include a compilable MWE so people can reproduce your problem without having to modify your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `floatpag` package to change the pagestyle for float pages:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{floatpag}
\floatpagestyle{empty} 

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{figure}[p]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=.95\textheight,width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{My caption.}
    \label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I use other floats in my paper that are more properly sized, so I'd like pages with those floats to still show the page number. Would you solution work for that?

Comment: @Anna If you want to only change a single float page, you can use `\thisfloatpagestyle{empty}`

Comment: That worked great, thank you!

Comment: @Anna You're welcome!